# Spotipy - Spotify API for Python invalid recommendation request

Tags: python, spotipy

when making a recommendations request such as:

```
recommend = sp.recommendations(target_energy = 0.5)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 62, in 
recommend = sp.recommendations(target_energy = 0.5)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 804, in recommendations
return self._get('recommendations', **params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 146, in _get
return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 124, in _internal_call
headers=r.headers)
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?target_energy=0.5&limit=20:
invalid request
```

any particular reason why this is giving an invalid request? I tried consulting the docs but I couldn't find an explenation

Comment: Can you provide more of your code so that we can replicate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supplying the correct parameters to your `recommendations` call.
You need to supply a `seed_artists`, `seed_genres` or `seed_tracks` parameter as well otherwise it'll be hard for the API to find recommendations.

The [official docs](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/browse/get-recommendations/) is a great resource.

Here's an example call using cURL

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?seed_artists=4NHQUGzhtTLFvgF5SZesLK&seed_tracks=0c6xIDDpzE81m2q797ordA&min_energy=0.4&min_popularity=50&market=US" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that one of the above seed parameters was compulsory